# How to grab data based on hex string pattern in webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to search a url for hex string pattern and add it to the current data being grabbed in the url. I did try some ways but its not working. Below is the working snippet which grabs successfully few data.

```
import requests, re, random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
}

url = "https://bscscan.com/address/0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4#readContract"
req = requests.get(url,header, timeout=10)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
creator = soup.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_trContract')
tokentracker = soup.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_tokeninfo')

print("Contract Owner:", creator.find('a', attrs={"title": "Creator Address"}).text)
print("Transaction ID:", creator.find('a', attrs={"title": "Creator Txn Hash"}).text)
print("Token Name:", tokentracker.find("a").text)
```

Current Output:

```
Contract Owner: 0xab3a68876925ecc5f361cefe78b3dae78b971436
Transaction ID: 0xc78e35353426d2851be008bf4de269652a4ce1746d025fae5aabd72454a31715
Token Name: StackDoge (STACKDOGE)
```

Wanted Output:

```
Contract Owner: 0xa36b9dc17e421d86ddf8e490dafa87344e76125b
Transaction ID: 0x4e79f8b1830ea35ad42bdc3622fb4914fce2bad3acc84bcdebbdfa44c9e4a119
Token Name: Binemon (BIN)

  1. DOGE:                      0xba2ae424d960c26247dd6c32edc70b295c744c43
  4. _marketingWalletAddress:   0x12345411294d0fddf644800e3a524cb73ffdfe7f
  8. deadWallet:                0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead
 11. dividenTracker:            0x7cf7ea291e26bc3d8796c876f1d63befbdc5f22c
 23. owner:                     0xab3a68876925ecc5f361cefe78b3dae78b971436
 28. uniswapV2Pair:             0xd6a499cbe432bfe88c62a27d7e1437ddafe3a95a
 29. uniswapV2Router:           0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e
```

Answer (score 1):

That data is present inside an `<iframe>`. You have to navigate to that `<iframe>`'s source and fetch data.

To get that `src` of `<iframe>`, you need to use selenium as it is being loaded by JavaScript.

Here is how it is done.

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", options=options)

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'}

url = 'https://bscscan.com/address/0xe1fd7b4c9debac3c490d8a553c455da4979482e4#readContract'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
iframe = soup.find('iframe', {'id': 'readcontractiframe'})['src']
driver.close()

r = requests.get('https://bscscan.com/' + iframe)
f_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
d = f_soup.find('div', {'id': 'readContractAccordion'}).find_all('div', class_='card shadow-none mb-3')

for i in d:
    print(list(i.stripped_strings))
```

```
['1. DOGE', '0xba2ae424d960c26247dd6c32edc70b295c744c43', 'address']
['2. DOGERewardsFee', '8', 'uint256']
['3. _isBlacklisted', '<input> (address)', 'Query', 'bool']
.
.
['30. withdrawableDividendOf', 'account (address)', 'Query', 'uint256']
```

Comment: may i know the iframe link or how to check on the iframe itself?

Comment: Write ```print(iframe)``` in the code. You'll know the link